# Modificar longitud de un vector en c++

Tags: c++, array

Quiero modificar la longitud de un vector y a la vez eliminar los elementos que quedan si la nueva longitud es menor a la longitud original del vector. No se si habrá palabras reservadas del lenguaje para hacer esto.
Es con este tipo de vector: `std::vector nombre[];`

Comment: ¿Y qué es exactamente un `vector`? ¿Te refieres a `std::vector`? ¿Un array de memoria dinámica tal vez? Deberías especificar un poco más

Comment: O sea, ¿quieres hacer un [`std::vector::resize`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mira este es un ejmplo de como hacerlo, espero que te sirva

```
vector<int> blabla;
for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    blabla.push_back(i);

blabla.resize(blabla.size()-1);

for(int i = 0; i < blabla.size(); i++)
    std::cout << blabla[i] << std::endl;
```

Comment: **gracias** me sirvio

Comment: no hay de que si puedes ponlo como respuesta util